# Помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста

Tags: php

```html
<?php

function end($m){
 $m = date('i');
 $m0 = $m % 10;
 if($m0 >= 5 && $m0 <=20 ){
  $res = 'минут';
 }
 else if($m0 == 1){
  $res = 'минута';
 }
 else if($m0 >= 2 && $m0 <= 4 ){
  $res  = 'минуты';
 }
 else{
  $res = 'минут';
 }
 return $res;
}

echo $m . ' ' . end($m); 
 
?>
```

Comment: Нет ошибки. Работает так, как и написано.

Comment: у меня не выводит на экран ничего

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Эникейщик  вот ошибка;                Fatal error: Cannot redeclare end() in C:\Users\AZ\Desktop\php\htdocs\mysite\index.php on line 22

Comment: @xes в `php` уже есть функция `end()` - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.end.php

Comment: А что еще есть в index.php ?

Comment: @Andrew Hobbit, ,больше ничего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php уже есть встроенная функция `end()`, поэтому называть так свои функции нельзя. Нужно переименовать её.

Comment: Нет ошибки. Работает так, как и написано.!!!!